# If $G$ is a group of order $36$ and $H$ and $K$ are its subgroups of order $18$ and $9$, then show that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group of order $36$ and $H$ and $K$ are its subgroups of order $18$ and $9$, then show that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

This is how I have perceived a solution:-

Here $H$ has order $18 =  3^2 \times 2 $. The number of Sylow $3$ subgroups $n_3 \equiv 1\pmod3$ and divides $2$ is $1$ which is unique, hence $H$ is a normal subgroup. The same applies for subgroup $K$ of order $9$. Hence $HK = KH$, therefore $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Why is $H$ normal? It contains a subgroup of order $9$ which is normal *in $H$*, but I don't see how you obtain $H$ normal in $G$

Comment: Use the formula $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$.

Comment: $H$ is normal in $G$ because it has index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: When you say "its subgroups of order $18$ and $9$", you are implying that $G$ has one and only one subgroup of order $18$ and one and only one subgroup of order $9$ (in which case, $K$ would necessarily be contained in $H$, and $HK$ would equal $K$). If you mean that $H$ is *some* subgroup of $G$ of order $18$, and $K$ is *some* subgroup of $G$ of order $9$, then the way to say that is to say that "$H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ of order $18$ and $9$", dropping the "its".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal.   Thus $H\triangleleft G$ (assuming there's a subgroup $H$ of order $18$).

Another basic result is that if $K,N$ are subgroups,  with $N$ normal,  then $KN=NK$ is a subgroup.

Thus $HK\le G$.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is not contained in $H$, then the largest intersection possible has order $3$. But then the set $HK\subseteq G$ has size at least $(18\cdot 9)/3=54>36$: contradiction. So, $K\le H$ and hence $HK=H\le G$.

Answer (score 0):

**ETA: I realized that I misunderstood the question. I instead gave a proof which established that the group $\langle H,K \rangle$ generated by $H$ and $K$ is a *proper subgroup* of $G$, and in fact $\langle H,K \rangle$ is $H$. From this it follows that $HK =KH = H$. It is a lot more work than needed to solve the OP however.**

HINT:

1. Let $\pi$ be any element in $G \setminus H$. Use the fact that $H$ has index $2$ in $G$ to show that $y\pi$ is in $H$ iff $y$ is in $G \setminus H$. [Indeed, the set $H\pi$ is a subset of $G$ with $H\pi$ disjoint from $H$, and for each $y \not \in H$, the element $y\pi$ is *not* in the set $H\pi$. But $H$ has index $2$ $\implies$ $G \setminus H$ $=H\pi$. So as $y\pi$ is not in $H \pi$, it follows that $y \pi$ is not in $G \setminus H$, or equivalently, $y \pi$ is in $H$.]
2. Use 1. to show that $K$ is infact a subset of $H$. [Suppose $K$ is not a subset of $H$. Then $K \setminus H$ is nonempty, so let us fix an element $\pi$ in $K \setminus H$. Then for each $y \in K \setminus H$, the element $y \pi$ is in $H$ by 1., and furthermore, $y\pi$ is also in $K$, because $K$ itself is a group. Furthermore, $\{y; y \in K \setminus H\}$ has the same cardinality as $\{y \pi; y \in K \setminus H\}$, and the cardinality of both sets is $|H \setminus K|$. So if $K$ is not a subset of $H$, then the string of relations $$|K \setminus H| = |\{y \pi; y \in K \setminus H\}$$ $$\le |H \cap K|$$ holds. So as $$|K|=|H \setminus K| +|K \cap H|,$$ it follows that $H \cap K$ is at least half of $K$. But as $|K|=9$ which is in particular, odd, it follows that any subgroup of $K$ with at least half the elements of $K$, is $K$ itself. But $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $K$ as well as a set with at least half the elements of $K$. Thus, it follows that $H \cap K$ must indeed be $K$ itself. And so $K$ is a subset of $H$.

The result follows immediately from $K$ being a subset of $H$.

Comment: This is a very long and indirect proof compared with the others suggested!